# javazic timezone format

Tags: java, timezone, debian, dst, zoneinfo

Where can I find documentation about the binary data format outputted by `javazic` (the files shipped in Debian's `tzdata-java` package)?

The standard format used in `/usr/share/zoneinfo` has no explicit concept of daylight savings time versus standard time. It only knows about a timezone having different offsets from UTC at different times of the year.

Nevertheless, there are some libraries (like Boost's [`time_zone_base`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#date_time.local_time.time_zone_base) class, and the Ruby [TZInfo](http://tzinfo.rubyforge.org/) library) that prefer to think about a time zone as having a "standard time" and then a daylight savings time with some offset from standard time, so they're not really compatible with the standard zoneinfo files.

I saw the documentation for the `javazic` format a long time ago, and I seem to recall that the data contained in `javazic` format may be a better fit for these libraries than the `zoneinfo` format. But I can't remember where the documentation is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the documentation I'm looking for is in the [sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfoFile.html) class.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, [`build.tools.javazic`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/build/tools/javazic/package-index.html) is a package for compiling the [Olson zoneinfo database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoneinfo) into Java zone information files. The API documentation is a little terse, but it might be a place to start.